# I can't stop the loop in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, pyautogui

Here is my problem, I'm a beginner and I try to loop a "find and click" on a specific image ( the "NON" button ), it works but the loop don't stop when all the images are clicked.

How can I tell it that when there's no image left to stop the loop and continue with the code?

here's my code:

```
NON2 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('NON2.png', grayscale=True, confidence=0.9)

while NON2:
    time.sleep(2)
    click = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('NON2.png', grayscale=True, confidence=0.9)
    pyautogui.click(click)

pyautogui.click(44,965)
```

and here's the screenshot of the "non" button:

[image: NON button]

Comment: NON2 never changes, so loop continues indefinitely.

Comment: Oh ! Ok, thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DISCALIMER** I don't know pyautogui.

You'll never update the NON2 button in the loop.
Try this:

```
NON2 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('NON2.png', grayscale=True, confidence=0.9)

while NON2:
    time.sleep(2)
    NON2 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('NON2.png', grayscale=True, confidence=0.9)
    pyautogui.click(NON2)

pyautogui.click(44,965)
```

Comment: Oh ! It works ! Thank you very much !! But.. I don't know what was the problem, the code is similar to what i've done exept you changed the "click" by "NON2"..

Comment: the problem in your code is that you never change the object you test. in other words in your code `NON2` is always valid because you'll never check if is still on the screen

Comment: Ok ! Thank you very much for your answer !